# How to define a hotkey in LyX to insert an inline listings?

Tags: listings, lyx

In LyX, I can define a hot-key for listing-insert. But in this case, what appears is the `\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}` environment. In fact I want to insert a inline listings command `\lstinline{...}`. There is no predefined lyx command for insert an inline listings. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Does the following do what you want?

```
command-sequence ert-insert; self-insert \lstinline{; char-forward; ert-insert; self-insert }; char-forward; word-backward
```

Press "alt-x" and insert that in the mini-buffer to test it. If it does what you want, make a shortcut for it.

Comment: This can insert ERT for inline listing. However it's not what I really want. I want the `xxxx` command in `command-sequence listing-insert; inset-settings; xxxx;` which can set  "inline true"  for the inset.

Comment: @goodluck, ah I see what you mean. I don't know how to automate that.

Comment: @goodluck Did you find a solution?